# How to open MaterialDesignInXAML Drawer from a button in a sub view or code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design

I'm having issues with the Material design xaml drawer and placing buttons within sub views / xaml files that should communicate with their parent views.

I have the following code within my main window view:

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost x:Name="MainDialogHost" Identifier="RootDialog" SnackbarMessageQueue="{Binding ElementName=MainSnackbar, Path=MessageQueue}">
  <materialDesign:DrawerHost x:Name="MainDrawer" IsLeftDrawerOpen="{Binding ElementName=MenuToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}">
    <materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>
      <DockPanel x:Name="MenuContent">
      </DockPanel>
    </materialDesign:DrawerHost.LeftDrawerContent>
    <Grid>
      <vw:Header/>
    </Grid>
  </materialDesign:DrawerHost>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Within my header user control I have the following:

```
<Grid>
  <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignHamburgerToggleButton}" IsChecked="False" x:Name="TestMenuToggle" Click="TestMenuToggle_ClickAsync"/>
</Grid>
```

If I place the toggleButton code from my header into the main window view, the drawer opens successfully. But when I move it back into the header sub view. It does not work.

Can adding the code to a sub view be achieved (Am I missing something) or will I have to access the main window view in my header view code behind and open it there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems like there is no way, It would have been great if there was an ID to target the DraweHost as in the DialogHost, but this is missing. the work around could be to extend the class and add more functionality